# how to change my onion URL?

Tags: url, onion-routing

I have my onion site online but I'd like to change my URL.

For example my URL looks like :

```
http://j3cjshcxrizpbq4txis7lk242hascwom5vwhvhdfvgpajqkwlzfrynad.onion/
```

But I would like to change my URL and have different URL onion or change my URL using my name like this:

```
http://dreadytofatroptsdj6io7l3xptbet6onoyno2yv7jicoxknyazubrad.onion/
```

This onion site has its name in the first part of the URL.

How could I do that?

Comment: This question is off-topic here since it is not actually about security. But if you search for [create vanity onion url](https://www.google.com/search?q=create+vanity+onion+url) you'll find many instructions on how to do this. Also, there is a separate stackexchange site [tor.se] for Tor related questions.

Answer (score 0):

For generating an URL starting with a defined string, you should user mkp224o: https://github.com/cathugger/mkp224o

But depending on your processor frequency and how many letters/numbers are added, it could be very slow to generate such a URL.